# Prolog code generates error

Tags: prolog

I want to understand why the next piece of code is not working.

```
modul(A,B,R):-A<B,R is B-A.
modul(A,B,R):-R is A-B.
```

This here extracts the Xth element from the list

```
extractFromList([H|_],X,R):- X is 0,R is H.
extractFromList([_|T],X,R):- X1 is X-1,extractFromList(T,X1,R).
```

This here computes the Manhattan distance of 2 points.The points are passed as a 2-element list. I put the write calls for debugging purposes

```
manhatan2(P1,P2,R):-
    extractFromList(P1,0,X1),write(X1),nl,
    extractFromList(P1,1,Y1),write(Y2),nl,
    extractFromList(P2,0,X2),write(X2),nl,
    extractFromList(P2,1,Y2),write(Y2),nl,
    manhatan(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,R).
```

running `manhatan2([10,1],[20,1],R).` prints

```
10,_L165,20,1,_L165 
ERROR: </2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
Exception: (8) modul(1, _G1122, _G1123)
? creep
```

Tracing this call I see nothing wrong with how `Y1` is computed yet i get `_L165`

Please help me understand. I don't need just a fix to this. I want to understand why this code is bad so I can avoid writing the same mistake in the future.

Many thanks

Comment: extractFromList(P1,1,**Y1**),write(**Y2**),nl, is this an error?

Comment: hmm.That indeed was the problem.Couldn't see the forest for the trees.